# PromeTheus Query Error while using label expression

Tags: prometheus, promql, metricbeat

I used the following query which works fine:

```
curl "https://ulvtzkt007.saifg.abc.com:9090/api/v1/query?query=kafka_consumergroup_group_lag"
```

But when I used the same query with label filter like below:

```
curl "https://ulvtzkt007.saifg.rbc.com:9090/api/v1/query?query=kafka_consumergroup_group_lag{job='prometheus'}"
```

I get an error.

Please see this screenshot for more details:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -g option with curl :

```
curl -g "https://ulvtzkt007.saifg.rbc.com:9090/api/v1/query?query=kafka_consumergroup_group_lag{job='prometheus'}"
```